# access parent function in extended class

Tags: php, class, instantiation, extends

I'm trying to become more competent with php. I have a question about parent classes. In the code below is there a way to call function `foobar()` from class a within the `$b` instantiation. Thanks

```
<?php 
  class foo {
    function callFooBar(){$this->foobar();} 
    function foobar(){echo('foobar of foo');}
  }
  class bar extends foo {
    function foobar(){echo('foobar of bar');}
  } 
  $b=new bar; 
  $b->foobar(); 
  echo("<br>");
  $b->callFooBar(); 
?>
```

Comment: You mean late static binding? `function callFooBar(){static::foobar();}`

Comment: I'm not familiar with that terminology.  I'd like to use '$b->something->foobar();' and get "foobar of foo" I know I can use '$f = new foo;' but is there a way to do it from '$b'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call the method from the class itself, you can use `self`:

```
function callFooBar(){self::foobar();}
```

An [example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/rKqUbo).

Using `$this` or `static` will give you the same results twice.

If you want to do it from a method in class `bar`, you have to use `parent`